# Isolate failure to PSU\Motherboard\Processor

Tags: hard-drive, boot, cpu, motherboard, power-supply

I have a 2.5 year old custom built PC which intermittently stopped booting a few weeks ago and has now completely stopped booting. The symptom remains the same, the fans and LED's spin up, I can hear the HDD and DVD drive turn on post which it reboots immediately. There's no display to the screen.

Configuration:
Pentium G4560, Gigabyte H110M, 2x8GB RAM, Zotac GTX 1050Ti GPU, 1x HDD, 2x SSD, 1x ODD

After some debugging, found out:

1. If I remove the 4PIN CPU connector while keeping everything else connected, the restarts stop, but there isnt any display on screen
2. If I disconnect everything else (including the front panel switches ,etc) except the 24 PIN and 4 PIN connector on the motherboard, the reboots continue

Given (1), I believe that this is not a PSU issue since the processor is fairly low power and if it was a PSU issue, the reboots would have stopped in (2) where the processor and motherboard were the only loads on the PSU. Is this a valid assumption? Also, any suggestions on how to isolate the problem further?

Comment: Did you try removing the GPU along with everything else? If not, do that. Pull it off the board and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @kicken , I did remove the GPU as well. The behaviour remains the same, reboot loop if the 4 PIN is connected, else the computer stays on

Comment: Take it to a repair shop.

Comment: @DavidPostill I ended up calling the Motherboard manufacturers customer care who confirmed this is a symptom of motherboard failure and helped me file a repair  request under warranty